# Website design collapse in android mobiles

Tags: css, android

We have written media query for android mobile devices which have the resolution (360x640) as below:

**For portrait:**

```
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px)  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 4) and (orientation: portrait){

// Our code goes here

}
```

**For Landscape:**

```
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px)  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 4) and (orientation: landscape) {

// Our code goes here

}
```

After we have written the media query as above, we have tested the output on a real mobile device. While we have checked it, we noticed that it looks good at first but when we open the keypad in mobile to type text in the HTML input-textbox, the website design is collapsing.

Is this because of media query syntax?

Below is the screenshot of the site in normal view:

[image]

Below is the screenshot of the site while opening keypad:

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Kindly attach screenshort

Comment: Attached the screenshots. Kindly have a look into the screenshots and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Is the hot searches section is native ui right ?

Comment: The hot searches section is from a third party plugin

Comment: From the screenshot i thing there is a padding/margin or position absolute property is assigned to Hot Searches autofill. Please check the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90434/discussion-between-magento-vsmarttec-and-jordy-s-chemparathy).